# How do you get into the basement room near Sinclair Spirits?

Tags: bioshock

How do you get into the basement room in Fort Frolic near Sinclair Spirits? The entrance is under a grate that won't open. The room is on the left, and the grate is under the number 24, on this map:

[image: Map of Fort Frolic]

Map segment taken from [Game Banshee](http://www.gamebanshee.com/bioshock/walkthrough/fortfrolic.php).

Comment: [This duplicate question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116802/how-do-you-access-the-locked-area-in-poseidon-plaza) has some screenshots that may be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism that removes the grate is inside Sinclair Spirits (the shop with the papier-mâché splicers lining the entryway).  Go behind the counter to press the button, and the storeroom off of the room you're in will be unlocked.  Head down there and take everything from the safe.  **The grate will remain in place until the safe is completely empty.**  If your wallet is full, find a vending machine and blow through some money, then return to the safe and clean it out.  You may notice that the papier-mâché splicer statues are gone when you're on your way out; this is normal and not a glitch.  Once you return to the common area, the grate should be gone and the basement open to you.

Comment: Yes, I did in fact ask this question entirely because I initially couldn't get that grate open, and had to discover the empty safe part myself when existing online guides didn't mention it.  I must have been the only guy walking around Rapture with a full wallet all the time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a button near a sign that says "More items below", near a service counter, this button will open two doors. A stuck door behind you and the grate.