# How do you access the locked area in Poseidon Plaza?

Tags: bioshock

I've been playing through Bioshock again, and there's an area in Poseidon Plaza which I can't figure out how to get to.

This is the place on the map:
[[image: Poseidon Plaza map]

click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzQmk.jpg)

This seems to be the (locked) entrance to it:
[[image]

click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0h4w.jpg)

How do I get in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go into **Sinclair Spirits** (left to the view on the second screenshot).
2. Find the switch behind the counter and use it.

   [image]
3. A door on the wall opposite to the counter will open.

   [image]

   Go through that door and go downstairs, where you will find a **Power to the People** machine. Use this machine.
4. After returning upstairs, the previously locked stairwell will be unlocked.

   [image]